# How to set the Image icon exact at bottom center of parent image on click using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, position

I have a three images for sample. i want to set the bottom image icon exact `center` of Parent image using `jquery`. I done it by setting the `"left" position` of the `div` containing the image icon(bottom) by hardcode `"left"` in pixel. But, i need to set it according to screen size and number of `parent images`. if user `click` on `image1` then, the `small image icon` must appear exact at `bottom centered` of `Parent image` similarly for other `images` using `jquery`

**[View Code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvH7H/)**

[image]

Help appreciated!

Comment: instead of px enter "left" value in %...

Answer (score 1):

You need a div that holds the 'pink' image with center alignment (text-align:center).
Use following snippets to your existing css and javascript

```
<style>
.image-holder
{
 display:block;
 height: 20px;margin-top: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.image
{
  height:20px;width:20px;vertical-align: top;
}    
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // use your selector to find the appropriate div, I am using div for this sample
    $("div").on("click",function(){
    $(this).append("<div class='image-holder'><img src='imagepath' class='image' ></div>");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use of "on" is NOT SUPPORTED in version 1.7. So, have used 2.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying!
I have modified my code including your code and with certain changes to work extact what i need is as follows:

**In css:**

```
.mydiv {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Shekhar img1") no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;

}
.row {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%
}

.image-holder
{
 display:block;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
    margin-top: 101%;
}

.image
{
  height:20px;width:20px;vertical-align: top;
}
```

**In html markup:**

```
<div id="header-image1" class="mydiv">

</div>
<div id="header-image2" class="mydiv">

</div>
<div id="header-image3" class="mydiv">

</div>

<div id="header-image4" class="mydiv">

</div>
```

**In script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".mydiv").on("click",function(){
    $("#dynamicdiv").remove();
    $(this).append("<div id='dynamicdiv' class='image-holder'><img src='imagepath' class='image' ></div>");
  });
});
```

**NOTE: Use of "on" is NOT SUPPORTED in version 1.7. So, have used 2.0.0 version.**

**[View Full Working Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TvH7H/16/)**

Thanks @Lav G